# Como pegar posição do item de uma AutoCompleteTextView (Android)

Tags: android, autocompletar

Preciso pegar a posição do item de uma autoCompleteTextView e passar os dados para outros campos. Até o momento meu código esta assim:

```
spinner_produtos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id)
    {
        //etCodigo_produto.setText(lista_produtos.getItem(position).getCodigo_produto().toString());
        codigo_produto = lista_produtos.getItem(pos).getCodigo_produto();
```

Porém não vem o item selecionado.
Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa do valor selecionado ou da posição do item selecionado em sua spinner ?

Comment: Posição do item, porem não é um spinner, somente a nomenclatura esta spinner, é um autoCompleteTextView

Comment: Leandro, tente usar a seguinte função int posicao = seuTextView.getSelectedItemPosition();

Comment: Tentei algo assim mais não deu certo
int posicao = autoCompleteTextView_produtos.getSelectedItemPosition();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, a melhor solução é percorrer o array e buscar a posição  do item selecionado, assim:

```
spinner_produtos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
                String selecao = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                int pos = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < lista_produtos.length; i++) {
                    if (lista_produtos[i].equals(selecao)) {
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Posição " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```